# Concatenating Simple Text with Spannable Text

Tags: android

I am having one static string and one dynamic and I am concatenating both the strings and setting into TextView.

For example :

```
textview.setText(getString(R.string.status)+" "+setSpannableText(mlist.get(position).getStatus()));
```

setSpannableText Method :

```
 private Spannable setSpannableText(String text) {
        Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(text);

        wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return  wordtoSpan;
    }
```

Now the issue is when I dont concate the static string while setting text in TextView like :

```
textview.setText(setSpannableText(mlist.get(position).getStatus()));
```

The above line works properly.

But when I do the below one it doesnt work :

```
textview.setText(getString(R.string.status)+" "+setSpannableText(mlist.get(position).getStatus()));
```

I am having 5 to 10 lines of this setting textview and each one is having different static string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should concatenate those two strings with **TextUtils.concat()** :

```
CharSequence text = TextUtils.concat(getText(R.string.status),  yourSpannable);

textview.setText(text);
```

It is because getText() returns String and when you **+** it with Spannable object, the result loses its **Spannable** values. For that there is special static methid in **TextUtils** class.